# Button Clicked in Xamarin Android to call Xamarin.Forms.Page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to call a Xamarin.Forms `Page` through an Activity in `Xamarin.Android`.

I had used `[Java.Interop.Export("btnOne1Click")]` to call the Xamarin.Forms `Page`.

The code runs without errors if I use `App.Current.MainPage = new RootPage();` But it does not navigate to that `Page`.

I don't want to call the `[Java.Interop.Export("btnOne1Click")]` on `MainActivity`.

```cs
[Activity(Label = "FailureActivity")]
public class FailureActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Failure);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.txt_go_onjobs);
    }

    [Java.Interop.Export("btnOne1Click")]
    public void btnOne1Click(Android.Views.View v)
    {
        try
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(typeof(RootPage));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms runs on one activity, which is most like your main activity.

There are two sample projects that show you how to communicate between native and form parts of the code, which can be found here:

1. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native
2. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

However, to answer your question, you would do something like the following:

```cs
button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.txt_go_onjobs);
button.Click += (sender, e) => {
    // this is your Xamarin.Forms screen
    StartActivity(typeof(FormsActivity));
};
```

Now, in your `FormsActivity` call this:

```cs
[Activity (Label = "FormsActivity")]            
public class FormsActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        LoadApplication (new App ());
    }
}
```